# Looping with mysql_fetch_array skipping over first row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble iterating through MySQL rows.  This is my current code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM translations
          WHERE iddoc = '$id'
          AND submitted = 1;";
$result= mysqli_query($query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($numrows > 0) {
    while($eachrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo $eachrow[0];
        echo ", ";
        echo $numrows;
   }
}
```

The result of this is:

```
6, 2
```

But if there are 2 rows, why is the while loop ending after only 1 iteration?  What am I understanding wrong?

**EDIT:  It appears to be displaying ONE LESS than the correct amount of rows.  I.E. the while loop is running 1 less time than it should.**

Comment: What is $numtrans?  And I'm assuming you left out your select query for a reason...

Comment: You sure there is only one row? did you run it in a mysql broswer?

Comment: The code as it is has absolutely no problem! Add more significant code

Comment: I'm wondering what `$numtrans` is, but I don't see any problem. I guess you have to add more code.

Comment: mistype- $numtrans is actually $numrows, fixed it.

Comment: `The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.` May have something to do with this?

Comment: I don't even know what unbuffered/buffered are, I'll look into it

Comment: @Neal, I ran it in sql browser, there are TWO rows.

Comment: @Hubrid is what is displayed? the 1st or the second row?

Comment: @Neal 2nd, which is the 6.  The 1st row is a 5.

Comment: @Neal In fact, on other pages too, only the 2nd (or maybe the last, there are only two entries for each) are displayed.

Comment: You're not using `mysqli_query` correctly here. You should **NEVER** introduce things like `$id` directly in the query but should instead use `?` placeholders and bind these values before executing the query. Failing to do this could lead to serious consequences.

Comment: @tadman Truthfully, I was using mysql_query, but I entered in mysqli_query because I didn't want to get a wave of answers saying depreceated AHHHHHHHHHHHHH

I'm only on local machine just testing things out, before prod or anything I'll port it all to mysqli

Comment: @Hubrid What tadman meant was to use the prepare statement, not just putting in the whole query.

Comment: and also, note here `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)`, it's not `MYSQL_NUM`, it's `MYSQLI_NUM`. Try it to see if it fixes the problem

Comment: @Hubrid There's a reason you get flack for using `mysql_query`. It's because it's a terrible anachronism from the 1990s. For your own sake stop using it as soon as possible. `mysqli` is almost the same and much easier to use properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found problem.  I was fetching the first row with

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

outside of the while loop, thus causing it to start on the second row and skip over the first.

Comment: @Hubrid... Look it up sometime.